# Harmonica - high draw note won't sound

Tags: harmonica

I have a strange situation in which i can't seem to play the draw (an 8 draw on a D harp) AT ALL on lip pursing, although i can do all the other notes, even the high ones.  But it's not broken because it plays OK if i tongue block across either the 8-9 (9 blocked) or the 7-8 (7 blocked).  Or even if i use my fingers to block both 7 and 9 and inhale! Can you suggest what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What model is it? Is it a new instrument?

Answer (score 2):

- 1) If it's a new harp, certain reeds my be stiff at first - you need
  to experiment with your embouchure until you find the correct
  approach to getting that note to sound properly, then continue doing
  so regularly when you practice. After a week or two, it should loosen
  up and you'll be able to play more normally.
- 2) If it's an older harp, quite often dirt and gunk will accumulate
  around a reed or hole, making it difficult to play. Harmonicas
  require constant maintenance to keep them clean and playing
  correctly. If you look under close light, often you can see gunk
  obstructing the hole or reed.

  The fix in that case is to clean your harp. It's a delicate
  process, and if you do it incorrectly you can trash the instrument 
  entirely. You can read up on it - there are some good sites that discuss
  it and some controversies as well, but it's probably better to have someone experienced do it for you.
  It often involves opening up the harp and touching or getting in between the
  reeds - delicate business.

  At any rate, never use solvents to clean, and avoid cotton swaps or any other   material that leaves lint. Water, rubbing alcohol and a lint-less
  cloth or something like lens cleaners are good. If you use water, hold your harp face down, so the water runs out the front and doesn't   accumulate around the reeds, which again could trash your instrument entirely.